# SQL Server Installation - No Installation type

Tags: installation, sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server on a new computer at work, but for some reason the installation is missing a step. Usually the steps listed on the left of the installation window go as follows:

- Global Rules
- Product Updates
- Install Setup Files
- Install Rules
- Installation Type
- Product Key
- License Terms
- Setup Role
- Feature Selection
- Feature Rules
- Feature Configuration Rules
- Ready to Install
- Installation Progress
- Complete

This new computer, when I run the install off of the disc image I always use, SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition, shows the following steps:

- Product Key
- License Terms
- Global Rules
- Microsoft Update
- Install Setup Files
- Install Rules
- Feature Selection
- Feature Rules
- Feature Configuration Rules
- Ready to Install
- Installation Progress
- Complete

This new computer has Windows 10 Pro, .NET is installed, I am running the setup as Administrator, I have uninstalled all SQL Server programs and reinstalled, there is no default instance. The hard drive grants full control for Administrators, I don't know what I am missing. It doesn't matter if I choose SQL Server Express or the Developer Edition. It seems like most other posts deal with a previously installed instance that is not visible in SSMS, or suggest to do what I have already done. I appreciate any insight into this issue.

Comment: So what is the problem? Which of the missing steps do you want that are no longer there? Is it all of them? And why?

Comment: Installation Type does not show, which means I cannot create an instance of SQL Server. If I run through with the available steps, no instance is installed.

Comment: Is it possible that there is already a version of SQL server installed on this machine? If you installed Visual Studio, usually there will be an instance installed with it.

Comment: First I checked in SQL Configuration Manager. Then I went to add/remove programs and deleted all SQL programs before I ran the installation again. I also used the SQL Discovery Tool in the installation center. The computer does not have Visual Studio.

Comment: This video shows the complete steps to installing SQL server 2014 on Windows 10 and it does not show the screen you are talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXvsKtX-boI . Are you certain that this screen should exist? It seems the "feature selection" screen is where you will chose what will get installed.

Comment: That video helped! Apparently, in features selection I have to select Database Engine Services. Twenty other computers this has never happened, I guess you never stop learning!

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then, so others can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When on Windows 10 with the SQL Server 2014 developer edition, you have to choose what you want installed in the "feature selection" screen. Just check the Database Engine Services in that screen and it will install it correctly.

The installation type screen no longer exists. Here is a nice video on the steps to follow for installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXvsKtX-boI

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but figure this might help someone else. I was trying to install SSAS on an existing SQL Server install, and was not being given that choice. For me, the reason why the Installation Type selector was missing, and also why I was unable to install SSAS, was because I had the SQL Server 2019 installer, but my existing SQL Server install was 2017.

I first had to upgrade to SQL Server 2019. Once I did that, the Installation Type option appeared, and I was properly able to select my existing install to add SSAS.